# SVG color hover - can't find any solution

Tags: html, css, svg, hover

For some days I've been trying to solve this, i just want to make a color change at hover on a SVG (**with only CSS**), I've found lots of tutorials (in and out of Stack) but none of them is working for me.

Can anyone tell me what can I do?
This is the SVG code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 19.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="-58 251 500 500" style="enable-background:new -58 251 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:#FFFFFF;}
</style>
<path id="svgbutton" d="M-328,271.1c-127,0-229.9,102.9-229.9,229.9S-455,730.9-328,730.9S-98.1,628-98.1,501S-201,271.1-328,271.1z M-139.2,580.8
    c-10.3,24.4-25.1,46.3-43.9,65.1c-18.8,18.8-40.7,33.6-65.1,43.9c-25.3,10.7-52.1,16.1-79.8,16.1s-54.5-5.4-79.8-16.1
    c-24.4-10.3-46.3-25.1-65.1-43.9c-18.8-18.8-33.6-40.7-43.9-65.1c-10.7-25.3-16.1-52.1-16.1-79.8c0-26.5,5-52.3,14.8-76.6l0,0l0,0
    l181.3,181.3c2.3,2.4,5.5,3.7,8.8,3.7s6.4-1.4,8.8-3.7l181.3-181.2l0.2-0.2c0,0,0,0,0,0.1c9.8,24.3,14.8,50.1,14.8,76.6
    C-123.1,528.7-128.5,555.5-139.2,580.8z"/>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M192,748.5c-66.1,0-128.3-25.7-175-72.5c-46.7-46.7-72.5-108.9-72.5-175c0-66.1,25.7-128.3,72.5-175
        c46.7-46.7,108.9-72.5,175-72.5c66.1,0,128.3,25.7,175,72.5c46.7,46.7,72.5,108.9,72.5,175c0,66.1-25.7,128.3-72.5,175
        C320.3,722.8,258.1,748.5,192,748.5z M192,278.5C69.3,278.5-30.5,378.3-30.5,501c0,122.7,99.8,222.5,222.5,222.5
        c122.7,0,222.5-99.8,222.5-222.5C414.5,378.3,314.7,278.5,192,278.5z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M192,604.5L67.5,479.9c-7.8-7.8-7.8-20.5,0-28.3c7.8-7.8,20.5-7.8,28.3,0l96.3,96.3l96.3-96.3
        c7.8-7.8,20.5-7.8,28.3,0c7.8,7.8,7.8,20.5,0,28.3L192,604.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

I tried to associate the svg with an id="svgbutton", but I don't know if i should put it into "img src" in HTML or on the SVG code itself.

Anyway, i tried these two and it didn't work as #svgbutton {fill:red}
Can any pacient person explain this for me?

Thank you!
(and sorry for the bad english)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.st0:hover` will allow you to change the `fill` when the white sections are hovered over **directly**:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.st0 {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}

.st0:hover {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-58 251 500 500" style="enable-background:new -58 251 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="svgbutton" d="M-328,271.1c-127,0-229.9,102.9-229.9,229.9S-455,730.9-328,730.9S-98.1,628-98.1,501S-201,271.1-328,271.1z M-139.2,580.8
    c-10.3,24.4-25.1,46.3-43.9,65.1c-18.8,18.8-40.7,33.6-65.1,43.9c-25.3,10.7-52.1,16.1-79.8,16.1s-54.5-5.4-79.8-16.1
    c-24.4-10.3-46.3-25.1-65.1-43.9c-18.8-18.8-33.6-40.7-43.9-65.1c-10.7-25.3-16.1-52.1-16.1-79.8c0-26.5,5-52.3,14.8-76.6l0,0l0,0
    l181.3,181.3c2.3,2.4,5.5,3.7,8.8,3.7s6.4-1.4,8.8-3.7l181.3-181.2l0.2-0.2c0,0,0,0,0,0.1c9.8,24.3,14.8,50.1,14.8,76.6
    C-123.1,528.7-128.5,555.5-139.2,580.8z"/>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M192,748.5c-66.1,0-128.3-25.7-175-72.5c-46.7-46.7-72.5-108.9-72.5-175c0-66.1,25.7-128.3,72.5-175
        c46.7-46.7,108.9-72.5,175-72.5c66.1,0,128.3,25.7,175,72.5c46.7,46.7,72.5,108.9,72.5,175c0,66.1-25.7,128.3-72.5,175
        C320.3,722.8,258.1,748.5,192,748.5z M192,278.5C69.3,278.5-30.5,378.3-30.5,501c0,122.7,99.8,222.5,222.5,222.5
        c122.7,0,222.5-99.8,222.5-222.5C414.5,378.3,314.7,278.5,192,278.5z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M192,604.5L67.5,479.9c-7.8-7.8-7.8-20.5,0-28.3c7.8-7.8,20.5-7.8,28.3,0l96.3,96.3l96.3-96.3
        c7.8-7.8,20.5-7.8,28.3,0c7.8,7.8,7.8,20.5,0,28.3L192,604.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

However, you probably want it to change colour when the inner black section is hovered over as well. In this case, you're looking for `svg:hover .st0`:

```css
body {
  background: black;
}

.st0 {
  fill: #FFFFFF;
}

svg:hover .st0 {
  fill: red;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="-58 251 500 500" style="enable-background:new -58 251 500 500;" xml:space="preserve">
<path id="svgbutton" d="M-328,271.1c-127,0-229.9,102.9-229.9,229.9S-455,730.9-328,730.9S-98.1,628-98.1,501S-201,271.1-328,271.1z M-139.2,580.8
    c-10.3,24.4-25.1,46.3-43.9,65.1c-18.8,18.8-40.7,33.6-65.1,43.9c-25.3,10.7-52.1,16.1-79.8,16.1s-54.5-5.4-79.8-16.1
    c-24.4-10.3-46.3-25.1-65.1-43.9c-18.8-18.8-33.6-40.7-43.9-65.1c-10.7-25.3-16.1-52.1-16.1-79.8c0-26.5,5-52.3,14.8-76.6l0,0l0,0
    l181.3,181.3c2.3,2.4,5.5,3.7,8.8,3.7s6.4-1.4,8.8-3.7l181.3-181.2l0.2-0.2c0,0,0,0,0,0.1c9.8,24.3,14.8,50.1,14.8,76.6
    C-123.1,528.7-128.5,555.5-139.2,580.8z"/>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M192,748.5c-66.1,0-128.3-25.7-175-72.5c-46.7-46.7-72.5-108.9-72.5-175c0-66.1,25.7-128.3,72.5-175
        c46.7-46.7,108.9-72.5,175-72.5c66.1,0,128.3,25.7,175,72.5c46.7,46.7,72.5,108.9,72.5,175c0,66.1-25.7,128.3-72.5,175
        C320.3,722.8,258.1,748.5,192,748.5z M192,278.5C69.3,278.5-30.5,378.3-30.5,501c0,122.7,99.8,222.5,222.5,222.5
        c122.7,0,222.5-99.8,222.5-222.5C414.5,378.3,314.7,278.5,192,278.5z"/>
</g>
<g>
    <path class="st0" d="M192,604.5L67.5,479.9c-7.8-7.8-7.8-20.5,0-28.3c7.8-7.8,20.5-7.8,28.3,0l96.3,96.3l96.3-96.3
        c7.8-7.8,20.5-7.8,28.3,0c7.8,7.8,7.8,20.5,0,28.3L192,604.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but it does not work for me D:
did you put the "svg:hover .st0" into the CSS or SVG code?

Comment: Into the CSS. It's targeting the `<svg>` element **itself**, so it must run from your stylesheet :)

Comment: But does the SVG document need to be associated to html, like the stylesheet? In my HTML i do not have a svg tag, I used "img src" to put the svg file. Does it make any difference? When I put the st0 {fill:color} into stylesheet nothing happens.

Comment: Hey, Obsidian Age, I did it!!!!
I put the svg code directly into the html's one, and that worked!!
Thank you very much for your help, if you can help me to find any other way to do this, like coding the hover into the svg file, I'll be very grateful (I already am)!